# Cognos 10 report not showing all values durign calculation

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I am having issues with a report i am making...

The goal of the report is to show by person the percentage they are assigned to a project, and then overall capacity.
(% allocated = allocated hours / month hours)

I started with hours per a project and overall percentage and had no 
issue:
 [image]

But when I change the “Allocated Hours” data item to Allocated Hours/Capacity the report only shows one of the project allocations but the overall is still correct!

[image]

As a test I then tried the data item to be Allocated Hours/160  and the report showed all the items.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea of where i am going wrong?

thanks!!

Comment: What is the value of capacity where you're getting 0s from your calculation?

Comment: Change the data expression to calculated and also try to aggregate numerator and denominator and then perform division.

Comment: I ended up forcing "Capacity" in from a list example May 2017 = 176